# How to retrieve data from shared memory

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory

I am trying to store pointers to elements of struct type in shared memory. But on fetching the same all I get is zeros.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;
typedef struct demo
{
    int sensorID;
    float value;
    int time;
}demo;

int main()
{
    key_t key;
    int shmid;
    demo *ptr;

    key = ftok("/home/dilbert/work",'R');
    shmid = shmget(key,4096*2, 0755 | IPC_CREAT);
    ptr = (demo*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0); //Is this step right?
                                            //I casted the void ptr into demo ptr type
    if(ptr == (demo*)(-1))                  
            perror("shmat");
    demo *pos = ptr;
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
            demo *A=new demo;  //Creating a struct elem
            A->sensorID=i+10;  //Storing some data
            A->value=2*i+98.344;
            A->time=3*i*1000;
            pos = A;           //Keeping the pointer to it in shared memory
            ++pos;             //Incrementing the pointer
    }

    pos = ptr;    //Reset the pointer back to start of shared memory. Might be going wrong here.
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)  //Now start printing the data.
    {
            cout<<"Sensor: "<<pos->sensorID<<"  Value: "<<pos->value<<"   Time: "<<pos->value<<"\n";
            ++pos;
    }
    //Just a demo program. So did not bother to delete the pointers in shared memory. I think I should because shared memory destruction will not call delete for its elements.
    shmdt(ptr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL); 
    return 0;
}
```

The result I get is :

```
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
Sensor: 0  Value: 0   Time: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code here

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
        demo *A=new demo;  //Creating a struct elem
        A->sensorID=i+10;  //Storing some data
        A->value=2*i+98.344;
        A->time=3*i*1000;
        pos = A;           //Keeping the pointer to it in shared memory
        ++pos;             //Incrementing the pointer
}
```

You're creating an object in non-shared memory. Furthermore, you're not storing a pointer into the shared memory, you're actually modifying the pointer itself (to point to local memory in fact).

Are you trying to store the actual object or just a pointer into the shared memory? If you mean to store the actual object, you'll want to use something like

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
        demo *A=new demo;  //Creating a struct elem
        A->sensorID=i+10;  //Storing some data
        A->value=2*i+98.344;
        A->time=3*i*1000;
        *pos = *A;         //Store object in shared memory
        ++pos;             //Incrementing the pointer
}
```

If you're trying to store a pointer, keep in mind that the pointer you store will almost certainly be invalid in another process and will not work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. 
Many thanks. I was thinking of storing the pointer to make the shared memory store much more data. As the elements of the struct can be of large size. The pointer will be of fixed size. But the fact that other process might not be able to extract the data is worrying. Will have to check more.

Comment: @NotAgain - do you think you might be able to accept this answer? It is not mandatory, but it is generally the best way to thank/acknowledge someone's help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are corrupting the value of `pos` in the for loop for **storing the data**. use `*pos = *A;` instead of `pos = A;`

And also think about that do you want to keep the memory location of newly created memory for `A` or you want to store the data from `A` to the shared memory. My change will store the data.

Comment: It worked. Many thanks.
I was thinking of storing the pointer to the struct elements as elements can be of large size. So was thinking of saving space and making the shared memory store more elements.